# php code not taking into account daylight saving time

Tags: php

I have the following code which shows daylight saving time is in effect and returns the correct date and time, and the timezone version being used. However, "Daytime" remains until 11pm local time rather than 10pm when "Night time" needs to show. I'm not at all good at coding and can't figure out the best/easiest way to get what I want. Please can anyone help?

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Adelaide');

$hour = idate('H');

if (($hour >= 6 && $hour <= 22)) {
    // after 6am and before 10pm
    $daytime = true;

    if ($daytime === true) {
        print "Daytime";
    }   
}
else {
    // 10pm to 6am the next day
    $daytime = false;

    if ($daytime === false) {
        print "Night time";
    }   
}
?><br />

<?php date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Adelaide');
echo date("I, l, F jS, Y, h:i:s",time());
?><br /><br />

<?php echo timezone_version_get(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$hour = date("H:i");   

 if (($hour >= date("06:01") && $hour >= date("22:00")) {
```

You also need to compare the **minutes** if the range of DayTime = 06 - 10 and NightTime = 10 - 06

Since they are holding the same hour, the only differences is their timing.
By such, comparison is DayTime = 06:01 - 22:00, other than that will be NightTime

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't using H mean 24 hour, so for 10pm it should be 22, shouldn't it? Wouldn't 10 represent 10am, not 10pm.

Comment: i think im being confused of your description.. what is your daytime range and nighttime range? @user8722983

Comment: Daytime is from 6am until 10pm, i.e. 2200 hours. Night time is from 10pm until 6am.

Comment: Thank you so very much AKZhang. That seems to be working.